# C++ function assigning 0 to reference variables output different value

Tags: c++, function, output, pass-by-reference

Can somebody help find the mistake in my coding? I'm supposed to pass the value 0 to reference variable in the function `init` to the struct `Bus`. I wrote the function `output` to print the values but the value of `b.Current`kept coming out as 16. Here is part of the coding:

```
struct Bus
{
    int Current;
    int Max;
};

void init(Bus &b)
{
    b.Current = 0;
    b.Max = 0;

}

void output(Bus &b)
{
    cout << "Passengers: \tactual: " << b.Current
         << "\tmaximum: " << b.Max << endl;
}

int main()
{
    struct Bus s;

    output(s);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Passengers:   actual: 16      maximum: 0
```

I tried changing things but nothing seems to work. Any idea how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling `init`?

Comment: If I take your sample code and try to [run it myself](https://godbolt.org/z/K9qa6Gvo1), a couple things. First, I have to add some `#include` and `using` statements to make it compile at all. Second, I just write `Bus s;` not `struct Bus s;` since this is C++ not C and the `struct` is unnecessary here. Third, I call `init(s);` to avoid the UB of reading uninitialized variables and I get the expected output. If this doesn't happen in your code, that means that the "part of the coding" you've shared doesn't contain your actual problem and more detail is needed.

Comment: What about `Bus() : Current(0), Max(0) {}` in the struct class definition? `struct Bus s{0,0};` should either work well.

Comment: This code looks suspiciously like a mix of C++ practices and C practices.  You may want to reconsider how you are learning C++.

Comment: I'm actually still studying the language. This is part of my homework and they gave a step-by-step instructions. This is just a small part of the task.

Comment: Btw, thanks everyone. I missed calling the function ```init```. That explains it. What a bad mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not really C++.

Having a free init function is not useful. Use a constructor instead or at least specify default values for its members.

```
struct Bus
{
   int Current = 0;
   int Max = 0;
};
```

No need for init.

Also use member functions for Bus. (And dont write `struct Bus s;`, just say `Bus s;`

```
struct Bus
{
   int Current = 0;
   int Max = 0;
   void output(ostream &out)
   {
       out << "Passengers: \tactual: " << Current
            << "\tmaximum: " << Max << endl;
   };
};

int main()
{
   Bus s;
   s.output(cout);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Your code is not really C++." Looks plenty like C++ to me. It just so happens that in this case, using an init function is unnecessarily over complex.

Comment: It is really a C program, not C++, since it leaves out all the C++ goodies.

Comment: C: init is a free function accessing the members of a struct.
C++: Init is not neccessary at all. A constructor would be the right thing to use.

C: `struct Bus s` is old C style.
C++: `Bus s` is  C++.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call init function after initializing Bus structure

Comment: Do or do not.  There is no try.

Comment: @Wyck • There is too a `try`, followed by a `throw` and then a `catch`.  There's also a `do ... while`.  But C++ lacks a `do not`.  Mandalorians do not like C++.